# how to provide cluster id to two namenodes in ha-hdfs

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I have configured HA-HDFS.
I am facing an issue with ClusterID Where the ClusterID of my namenodes and datanodes don't match therefore, my datanodes are not getting started.
How to provide the same ClusterID for both namenodes.
Thanks.

Comment: Do both servers have the same `hdfs-site` and `core-site` XML?

Comment: Yes, both servers have the same hdfs-site and core-site XML?